# How to convert textarea input to pdf using itext and make it downloadable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pdf, itext

Friends, 
I am have implemented a jsp form which takes inputs like title, description and content of the pdf file. When the jsp form is submitted, the pdf is created using itext with the help of the servlet called 'pdfGenServlet.java'.

my jsp form is

```
<form action="pdfGenServlet" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                    <!-- input notes title-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title of the notes" name="title">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- input notes description-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter short description" name="description">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea name="content" id="myEditor"></textarea>

                     <div id="button-panel" class="panel panel-default">
                          <p>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><strong> Create Note</strong></button>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset"><strong>Reset</strong></button>
                          </p><!-- buttons -->
                     </div><!-- panel Button -->

                    </div>

                </form>
```

The servlet 'pdfGenServlet.java'

```
    @WebServlet("/pdfGenServlet")
  public class pdfGenServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      try {
            // Get the text that will be added to the PDF
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            //Font for using with itext
            Font bfBold18 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)); 
            Font bfBold12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)); 

            String title = request.getParameter("title");
            String description = request.getParameter("description");
            String notes_content = request.getParameter("content");
            Date date = new Date();

            System.out.println(title);
            System.out.println(description);
            System.out.println(notes_content);
            System.out.println(date.toString());

            if (description == null || description.trim().length() == 0) {
                 description = "You didn't enter any text.";
            }

            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            //document.add(new Paragraph(title));
            document.addCreationDate();
            document.add(new Paragraph("TITLE: ", bfBold18));
            document.add(new Paragraph(title,bfBold12));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(String.format("Created on: " + date.toString())));
            document.add(new Paragraph("DESCRIPTION: ", bfBold18));

            document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(notes_content,bfBold12));
            // step 5
            document.close();

            // setting some response headers
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            // setting the content type
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            // the content length
            response.setContentLength(baos.size());
            // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            baos.writeTo(os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(DocumentException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

}

The output of the above servlet and form(after submission) is pdf viewer of chrome embedded into my page that displays the pdf but when i click save button that is in the pdfviewer at the right-bottom corner. The pdf file does saves but it shows failed.

[image: The output of the above servlet and form(after submission) is pdf viewer of chrome embedded into my page that displays the pdf but when i click save button that is in the pdfviewer at the right-bottom corner. The pdf file does saves but it shows failed.]

Also as u can see in the content 'example example ....' the

tags come due the paragraph applied by the froala editor that is my textarea input. Instead of applying the paragraph it appears like '

and

'.Please help with that too.

How can i make the pdf file generated downloadable into a directory please help.

Comment: So you turn the plain HTML textarea in an editbox for rich text (froala). Search for HTML-to-PDF.

Comment: @Joop Eggen Yeah I did.and searched for html to pdf  can u help me for the 'download' problem .

Comment: I have create a web project in eclipse. Then I copied all your code and it worked smoothly without any issue in both FireFox and Chrome. Also downloaded successfully.

So I want to know what actually are you doing? What is the pdf viewer in chrome that you are using in your page? Are you not submitting your form to the servlet? Are you displaying pdf inside some iframe etc? Can you share more details? code?

Comment: If you are talking about the pdfviewer chrome extension, it is something i have not used. Rather without installing it the pdf was downloaded and displayed. I am checking with this extension now.

Comment: @muasif80 yes, i am displaying the whole thing in iframe. And pdf viewer is default one that chrome opens  when opening any pdf file.

Comment: @muasif80  I tried as u said and it was downloadable. The problem is i m trying to use it in iframe and i've got no options. I have to use the iframe.can u suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I am able to do this successfully using exactly your code but making these two changes.

1. Put `method="get"` in the `<form>` tag in the jsp
2. Change `doPost` to `doGet` in the servlet

and it should work as it has worked for me too.

Do tell me if it works.

The PDF document did show up in PdfViewer as well successfully saved too.

Comment: I am happy that it has worked for you. Will be happier if you up vote this in addition to accepting the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the HTML tags use the following library which will convert HTML/CSS to PDF format:

https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

it uses iText under the covers and will save you the the trouble of building your document programatically.

To have your PDF downloaded rather than display in the browser do:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name + ".pdf");
```